# C# Convert a 2-dimensional array into a dataset / datatable

Tags: c#, dataset, multidimensional-array

does anyone know how to turn a 2-dimensional array into a dataset or datatable in c#?

Source: a range of values from excel (interop) in an object[,] array.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please take a look at the following article

[Converting an Excel Spreadsheet to a DataSet, DataTable and Multi-Dimensional Array](http://naspinski.net/post/Converting-an-Excel-Spreedsheet-to-a-DatSet2c-Datatable-and-Multi-Dimensioanl-Array.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dataset / datatable in code:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx

From there you would loop through your array and populate the rows and their columns with the array information.

Answer (score 1):

Option given by mr.phoenix should work. If you are stuck with dealing with arrays...here is some pseudocode.

```
var sample = {{0, 1}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}, {6, 7}, {8, 9}};
var table = new DataTable("SampleTable");

// iteration logic/loops for the array
{
   var newRow = table.NewRow();
   newRow["Col1"] = sample[i,j0]; // like sample [0,0]
   newRow["Col2"] = sample[i,j1]; // like sample [0,1]
   table.Add(newRow);
}
```